# Can not use a model in a component template

Tags: angular

I have the following class:

```
export class Constants {

public static cREQUESTED_SERVICE: string = "RequestedService";
}
```

and I have the following template (Service.component.html) of component (Service.component.ts):

```
<label>{{Constants.cREQUESTED_SERVICE}}</label>
```

I have already imported (Constants) class inside (Service.component.html). The problem is: The label is displayed empty and the following error is logged in the console:

*Subscriber.js:240 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cREQUESTED_SERVICE' of undefined*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your Service.component.ts, create another getter method like this

```
import { Constants } from 'your/path/to/this/file/Constants';

export class ServiceComponent {
  get ConstantsClass() {
    return Constants;
  }
}
```

in template

```
<label>{{ConstantsClass.cREQUESTED_SERVICE}}</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

When ever you are using constants you should be using them as injectable() as they remain same through out the life cycle of the application(singleton) just like any other provider

```
@Injectable()
export class Constants {

public readonly cREQUESTED_SERVICE: string = "RequestedService";
}
```

In your component you should inject into constructor and use

```
constructor(private cons : Constants){}

this.cons.cREQUESTED_SERVICE
```

Comment: I do not want to add the class as a provider

Comment: but that is the way to do. because you should not have more than one instance

Comment: @Aravind you can not access static property from class instance

Comment: @TiepPhan you are right didnt notice that :) Updated

Comment: @Aravind I am using the class as a global class and I do not want to add a refrence for it in each component.

Comment: by global where are you using it.